# How to set custom settings for worksheet using Excel javascript API?

Tags: javascript, excel, worksheet, office-js

I can set settings for whole workbook like here:

```
Office.context.document.settings.set("myKey", JSON.stringify(myValues));
```

Is there way to do the same but for specific worksheet ?

Comment: If there's no API support you could use the worksheet name in the key.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I think it is not very good idea because after renaming it lost relation between key and worksheet. Second problem will come if user move worksheet to another workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retrieve the [Worksheet](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheet).id property and include it as part of each key you set.

(Worksheet names are also exposed to the API, but the user can change them, so id is recommended here.)

-Michael (PM for Office add-ins)

Comment: What if the user move or copy sheet to another workbook ? Is there way copy settings to new workbook ?